# Detect image links and embed them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do, it write a javascript function where you give it a load of text, and it will look for URLs which end in `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.gif`, `.png` etc, and then replaces them with the code for an embedded image. So, for example, a text like:

> `Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet shank pork loin ground round beef meatloaf landjaeger tongue chicken strip steak short loin jowl pork chop meatball. Doner shank sausage, tri-tip jerky frankfurter tongue. Venison meatloaf kielbasa, hamburger ball tip tongue beef boudin shoulder spare ribs landjaeger short loin shank. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jzdnfSEhmEQ/UDvjPnb-Z0I/AAAAAAAACN4/jTQMom9Fr1c/s320/improvKitchen_howToCookBacon_00.jpg Ham hock ribeye swine sirloin tri-tip kielbasa turkey. Venison strip steak landjaeger corned beef ribeye, pig t-bone pancetta fatback drumstick short ribs sausage pork swine turkey. Jerky chuck bacon turducken doner salami andouille short ribs pork kielbasa drumstick pork chop.`

Would return

> `Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet shank pork loin ground round beef meatloaf landjaeger tongue chicken strip steak short loin jowl pork chop meatball. Doner shank sausage, tri-tip jerky frankfurter tongue. Venison meatloaf kielbasa, hamburger ball tip tongue beef boudin shoulder spare ribs landjaeger short loin shank. <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jzdnfSEhmEQ/UDvjPnb-Z0I/AAAAAAAACN4/jTQMom9Fr1c/s320/improvKitchen_howToCookBacon_00.jpg" /> Ham hock ribeye swine sirloin tri-tip kielbasa turkey. Venison strip steak landjaeger corned beef ribeye, pig t-bone pancetta fatback drumstick short ribs sausage pork swine turkey. Jerky chuck bacon turducken doner salami andouille short ribs pork kielbasa drumstick pork chop.`

---

I already have a function for links which I found in another SO post if that is of any help:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Comment: So the function you found does not solve your problem, correct?

Comment: Might not be a good idea. A url that ends with any of the image extensions can also be scripts. Just saying.

Comment: The function I found converts URLs to hyperlinks. Is there any way to modify the function so that it looks for image extensions as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you just need to change that replace to `<a>` tag markup to an `<img>`. And add a regexp pattern to check for `.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png`.

```
function replaceURLWithImage(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<img src='$1'/>"); 
}
```

See this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4H9B/1/).

Comment: Problem is that that will find links like http://www.google.com and try to turn them into images. It needs to look at the URL extension and only match image extensions.

Comment: ah yes sorry. I've updated the `regexp` and the jsfiddle demo.